# Python scrapy login using session cookie

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape from sites after authentication. I was able to take the JSESSIONID cookie from an authenticated browser session and download the correct page using urlopener like below.

```
import cookielib, urllib2

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
c1 = cookielib.Cookie(None, "JSESSIONID", SESSIONID, None, None, DOMAIN,
        True, False, "/store",True, False, None, False, None, None, None)
cj.set_cookie(c1)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
fh = opener.open(url)
```

But when I use this code for creating scrapy requests (tried both dict cookies and cookiejar), the downloaded page is the non-authenticated version. Anyone know what the problem is?

```
cookies = [{
    'name': 'JSESSIONID',
    'value': SESSIONID,
    'path': '/store',
    'domain': DOMAIN,
    'secure': False,
}]

request1 = Request(url, cookies=self.cookies, meta={'dont_merge_cookies': False})
request2 = Request(url, meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True, 'cookiejar': cj})
```

Comment: Did you tried just `cookies={'JSESSIONID': SESSIONID}`?

Answer (score 2):

You were able to get the JSESSIONID from your browser.

Why not let Scrapy [simulate a user login](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login) for you?

Then, I think your JSESSIONID cookie will stick to subsequent requests given that :

- Scrapy uses a **single cookie jar** (as opposed to [Multiple cookie sessions per spider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider)) for the entire spider
  lifetime containing **all your scraping steps**,
- the COOKIES_ENABLED setting for the cookie middleware defaults to
  true,
- dont_merge_cookies defaults to false :

  > When some site returns cookies (in a response) those are stored in the
  >   cookies for that domain and will be sent again in future requests.
  >   That’s the typical behaviour of any regular web browser. However, if,
  >   for some reason, you want to avoid merging with existing cookies you
  >   can instruct Scrapy to do so by setting the dont_merge_cookies key to
  >   True in the Request.meta.
  >
  > Example of request without merging cookies:
  >
  > ```
  > request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
  >                                cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'},
  >                                meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True})
  > ```

Comment: I alwas see every login example end here ` # continue scraping with authenticated session...`  yet thats the exact last step most people have trouble with. I'm trying to use scrapy and the login is successful, yet my next request is still unauthenticated and fails with 403 error